ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 121
I'm working with ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, version: 8.0.302 and I'm getting an error

Exception unhandling

mainly due to wrong connection string format while my connection string format looks like this in appsettings.json :
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InvestmentProj;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}


It seems unlikely that you're getting the error you reported from the connection string that you've posted. Is it possible that some kind of transform is being applied to give you a different connection string (e.g. appsettings.Development.json)? Assuming you don't have a plain-text password in the connection string, you might want to try logging your connection string to see how it's appearing. Also check the various answers to this similar question

The error is index 121,so you can check if the config "MultipleActiveResultSets" is wrong or  what configuration is missing.You can lean more about ConnectionStrings  to visite this website: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
